# Xcode 13.0 stuck while installing on macOS BigSur 11.6

Tags: app-store, macos-big-sur, xcode13

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour when updating Xcode from AppStore.

Screenshot:
[Xcode 13.0 stuck while installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xh0n.png)

I've tried:

1. Deleting Xcode then reinstall.
2. Free up storage space on Mac.
3. Connect to another WIFI.
4. Disabled VPN.

but no luck

Comment: Same here ... its almost already taken 7 hours and still installing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Xcode 13 does take a long time to finish update and install (took me a couple of hours, and it did at times seemed like it stopped installing and was stuck, but it does finish installing eventually - so maybe just be prepared that it might take up to 4-5 hours.
2. You mention downloading from the App Store, so not sure if you are aware - but you can download it also from the Apple Website Developer Resources: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/ (some people found it was easier or took less time)
3. There is also a site specifically for Xcode releases, https://xcodereleases.com
   It is Not an Official Apple site, but it All downloads are hosted By Apple (download links on this site take you directly to Apple’s download pages). It’s also very well organized.

Comment: Thank you so much for input. I wasn't patient enough to wait couple of hours. I do however got it installed finally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it, on the M1Pro, is using only the high-efficiency cores, and they max out.